# Implementation of an alphabetic sort on a list, equals override impossible

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of object to sort alphabetically on an attribute. I can't  override the equals method on this object because it's a generated class, my implementation will be deleted during the next generation. 
I think I will implement this sort in a toolbox class. 
Is there a way to not reinvent the wheel?

Comment: So your implementation will be deleted at the next revision? Are you just trying to do a prototype?  You can't make a utils class that will be safe from deletion?

Comment: `equals` wouldn't help you [much] defining an order anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
class A{
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public A() {
    }

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
aList.add(new A("abc"));
aList.add(new A("sda"));
aList.add(new A("aaa"));
Collections.sort(aList,new Comparator<A>() {

            public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
class Foo {
    public String field;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();

            ....        

    Collections.sort(foos, new Comparator<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
            return o1.field.compareTo(o2.field);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). You only need to implement the comparator to compare your attributes

Answer (score 0):

you can use comparator, let's says you are sorting a list (`myList`) of `Person` with their alphabetical name (`getName()`).

```
List<Person> myList = new ArrayList<Person>(keys);
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Person>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    String s1 = p1.getName();
    String s2 = p2.getName();
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
  }     
});
```